# Open jar from another jar

Tags: java, memory, jar, allocation

The same old problem ... I want to run my jar on Mac or Linux with high memory allocation. I do not want the user to open the Terminal and write **java -XMx512 -jar MainJar.jar** manually.

I have seen a lot of solutions to fix this ... But i was wondering if this might work : "**Executing the Terminal command *java -XMx512 -jar MainJar.jar* in Jar(B) to initialize Jar(A) with 512 MB memory allocation.**".

In Jar(B) i have tried this code to run Jar(A) and it worked fine :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   String jarName = "MainJar.jar";  // Jar(A) name.
   Desktop.getDesktop().open( new File( jarName ) );
}
```

But still i did not allocate memory for Jar(A) when initialized from Jar(B), so can i write a code in Jar(B) to run the Terminal and give it the command to execute it :
"**java -XMx512 -jar MainJar.jar**" ?

**------------------------------ Edited as requested to be more clear.**

Comment: **Running my main big jar from another small jar, after allocating its memory** How this is the solution, can you explain a bit

Comment: @org.life.java: I have edited the question to be more clear as requested.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you mean, but you want to run a jar file (B), and whilst running one jar, start a secondary process which runs your main jar file (A) with some VM arguments? I am not sure if this is possible, or if it allowed. Doesn't sound like a very stable way of handling the JVM. How about a shell script instead? You'll get an executable, and can easily pass arguments to JVM.

Comment: @posdef : Thanks ... Can a shell script be executable(double clicked) + Can it run on Mac + Linux ?

Comment: @Brad: a `.sh` file should run on any UNIX based system, and that includes Mac OSX. Otherwise you can also have shell specific scripts such as a bash script. Honestly I have never tried to double click on a shell script, gotta try that out.. :)

Comment: @posdef: Well, i was asking as i have already tried double clicking it in Mac ... It just opens the shell script in the default Mac text editor ... I don't want my users to hate me :) . I need to make things as simple as possible.

Comment: @Brad: two things you might want to try: 1) `chmod +x` so that your shell script has execution rights ;) and 2) see if you can change how ".sh" files are handled by default. On my Linux machine it asks me to run or to display its contents upon double clicking.

Comment: Thanks a lot posdef ... That shell file is making me crazy on Mac. Since this topic was about another quesition, i will open another question for the shell file in Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Runtime.exec()` or a ProcessBuilder to accomplish this.

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-XMx512M", "-jar", "MainJar.jar").start();
int result = proc.waitFor();
```

But honestly I think it's an awful solution.  I would favour an installation package like InstallAnywhere.  Failing that I would use a shell script to launch the Jar.  Encapsulating it in a Jar where it can't be edited is annoying to users and now you have parallel dependencies rather than a single file.

If you were going to take this route, it would be possible to use the same Jar for both purposes.  Add your class file to launch with the correct parameters to the Jar, say `AppLauncher.class`.  We'll assume your program's real code starts at `Main.class`.

```
public class AppLauncher {
     public static void main(String... args) {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-XMx512M", "-cp", "MyJar.jar", "Main").start();
        int result = proc.waitFor();
     }
}
```

Then you would [have your Manifest file of the jar point to this main class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

```
 Main-Class: AppLauncher
```

You would then execute this jar via

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Or through file associations (double click).

When it runs, it executes the command `java -Xmx512M -cp MyJar.jar Main` which runs the main method of the Main class of your jar.  The same jar is used in both invocations: the first time it automatically runs `AppLauncher.main()` via the manifest file, the second time `Main.main()` via an explicit process call.

This is still fragile of course.  For one thing, it assumes that the working directory is set to the folder that contains your jar file.  That's not always true.

**Edit**: Just in case you're not convinced to do otherwise, and actually take the ProcessBuilder route, there's more to it than just what I noted.  [There are pitfalls to avoid](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  For instance, I didn't read from the process's output stream (using `Process.getInputStream()`) so if child Java process outputs anything to stdout, it will freeze when the OS buffer is filled.

Comment: I like the idea of executing the command from the same Jar ... But i still can't get how to do it. What will i write in the 1st Main-Class ?

Comment: @Brad: I hope @Mark doesnt get upset for stealing his thunder, but what he suggests, I believe, is that you write that code in your small jar (B). When you run (B) it then creates a `Process` which then executes your main jar (A). Take a look at  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark ... I think i am convinced that using this solution is not stable. I am trying now to use a shell script. I hope it will run fine.